# Sort a List<T> by one of T's property

Tags: c#

I have a `List<T>`

How can I sort it ascendingly by one of T's int property?

I'm aware that I could create my own method to this manually but is there any way to this concisely like `List<T>.Sort`( by T's int property ); ?

Comment: Are you allowed to use LINQ?

Comment: Do you mean generically sort by a property, or just a general `List<T>` that you have full access too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use Enumerable Orderby to sort by it's property.

```
List<yourType> yourCollection = YourSourceList.OrderBy(e=>e.YourProperty).ToList();
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks for your feed back. I changed it. it's not LINQ. it's simple Enumerable class.

Comment: `Enumerable.OrderBy` and `ToList` are Linq methods and `ToList` creates a new `List` even if there's already one. The purpose of `List.Sort` (or `Array.Sort`) is to avoid creating an new collecton because that doubles the required memory(temporarily):

Comment: @TimSchmelter that i know. ToList() creates new one. Sort() will do alter in the same List. so Sort is Efficient.

Comment: Linq is what's sitting in it's namespace and `Enumerable` is part of the `System.Linq` namespace. It's `Linq-To-Objects`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx):

```
list.Sort((t1, t2) => t1.IntProperty.CompareTo(t2.IntProperty));
```

A less efficient but more readable approach is using `Enumerable.OrderBy`:

```
list = list.OrderBy(t => t.IntProperty).ToList();
```

Comment: Who wants to comment the downvote?

Comment: 3 downvotes for a correct answer? wtf?

Comment: +1 voted up for the good answer and to reduce the Downvote effects :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 List<T> lst=List<T>.OrderBy(x => x.Property).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own [Comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx) class. And then sort using that class e.g:

```
myList.Sort(new MyListComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Try This code to your list for sorting ASC/DESC

```
 List<HRDocumentCheckList> ser=new List<HRDocumentCheckList>();
 ser.OrderByDescending(q => q.Document.Id).ToList();
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

For folks who doesn't have the privilege to use Lamda expression approach, which was accepted as answer can follow the below given approach. The core idea is to implement `IComparable<Person>` whereby checking any specific property/field defined within object and here it is '`Person`'.

```
public class ConsoleApp
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Person> p = new List<Person>();
            p.Add(new Person() {Age = 25, Name = "Jo"});
            p.Add(new Person() {Age = 10, Name = "Jo"});
            p.Add(new Person() {Age = 2, Name = "Jo"});
            p.Sort();

        }
    }

    public class Person : IComparable<Person>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(Person other)
        {
            return other == null ? 1 : Age.CompareTo(other.Age);
        }
    }
```